# How to login a user from the Controller in cakephp4? Using the authentication plugin

Tags: authentication, cakephp, controller

I build a application, that has a normal login with the Authentication plugin, and other form of login that happens in the controller. In cakephp3 we can do that with $this->Auth()->login , $this->Auth()->setUser, etc. But in cakephp4 the Authentication plugin doesn't have a $this->Authentication->login/setUser. The questions is how do i do that?.

I obtaing the user in the controller and i don't have any way to login that user.

I'm wondering if any of you have encounter this problem

This is my authentication service:

```
public function getAuthenticationService(ServerRequestInterface $request): AuthenticationServiceInterface
    {
        $service = new AuthenticationService();

        // Define where users should be redirected to when they are not authenticated
        $service->setConfig([
            'unauthenticatedRedirect' => Router::url([
                'prefix' => false,
                'plugin' => null,
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'login',
            ]),
            'queryParam' => 'redirect',
        ]);

        $fields = [
            IdentifierInterface::CREDENTIAL_USERNAME => 'email',
            IdentifierInterface::CREDENTIAL_PASSWORD => 'password'
        ];
        // Load the authenticators. Session should be first.
        $service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Session');
        if ($request->getParam('action') == 'googleLogin') {
            $service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Form', [
                'fields' => $fields,
                'loginUrl' => Router::url([
                    'prefix' => false,
                    'plugin' => null,
                    'controller' => 'Users',
                    'action' => 'googleLogin',
                ]),
            ]);
        } else {
            $service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Form', [
                'fields' => $fields,
                'loginUrl' => Router::url([
                    'prefix' => false,
                    'plugin' => null,
                    'controller' => 'Users',
                    'action' => 'login',
                ]),
            ]);
        }
        // Load identifiers
        $service->loadIdentifier('Authentication.Password', compact('fields'));

        return $service;
    }
```

and this is the controller

```
$this->Authorization->skipAuthorization();

        $data = $this->request->getData();
        $email = $data['email'];

        $repository = new UserRepository($this->Users);
        $user = $repository->findUserByEmail($email);

        $response = $this->response;

        if (!empty($user)) {
            $response->withStatus(201);
            return $response;
        } else {
            $user = $this->Users->newEmptyEntity();
            $dataUser['username'] = $email;
            $dataUser['email'] = $email;
            $dataUser['password'] = 'esquemaPerfecto';
            $dataUser['role'] = 'cliente';
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $dataUser);
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Authentication->setUser($user);
                $sendEmail = new EmailHelper($dataUser['email'], 'Vehiculos de Primera mano Registro', 'Usted se ha registrado con exito en la pagina de Vehiculos de Primera Mano y su contraseña es ' . $dataUser['passwords']);
                $sendEmail->send();

                $response->withStatus(200);
                return $response;
            }
        }

        $response->withStatus(400);
        return $response;
    }
```

All ideas are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Migration from the AuthComponent](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/migration-from-the-authcomponent.html) docs section

Any place you were calling AuthComponent::setUser(), you should now use setIdentity():

```
// Assume you need to read a user by access token
$user = $this->Users->find('byToken', ['token' => $token])->first();

// Persist the user into configured authenticators.
$this->Authentication->setIdentity($user);
```

Comment: That is correct!. I was searching trough the documentation of authentication plugin, but it never occurred to me search inside of "migration from the AuthComponent". Thank you so much!